# Selecting an element with an ID generated by template

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to create a table such that each cell has a unique ID corresponding to its coordinates. This is no trouble in Polymer; I've just done

`<table id="table">
        <template repeat="{{ file in files }}">
            <tr>
                <template repeat="{{ rank in ranks }}">
                    <td id="{{file}}{{rank}}">{{ space }}</td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </template>
</table>`

where `ranks`, `files` and `space` are keys on the object passed to the Polymer() function (arrays and a string, respectively). This all works as expected.

The problem now is selecting one of the table cells by its template-generated ID. Doing

`var place = file + rank;
this.$.place.innerHTML = 'foo'`

doesn't work, as it throws a "cannot set innerHTML property of undefined" error. I cannot for the life of me come up with a way to tell Polymer's custom node-finding syntax how to look for an ID that isn't explicitly defined in the template (such as '#table').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic node finding on elements with IDs is setup when the element is first set up. AFAIK, you can't use it for nodes with dynamically created IDs. Instead, use `this.shadowRoot` and query for the node:

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById(place).innerHTML = 'foo';
```

---

```
var place = file + rank;
this.$.place.innerHTML = 'foo';
```

will never work. `place` is a variable and not a property on `$`. You'd need to use array notation:

```
this.$[place].innerHTML = 'foo';
```

However, this won't work because the ids are created dynamically, after the element is prepared.

Comment: I swear to your preferred celestial being that I tried `this.shadowRoot` but I could be mistaken. Cheers for the answer - I'm going to try this when I've had more sleep and caffeine.

Comment: Aaaand it worked. I guess I must have tried every other variation on `shadowRoot`. Thank you :)

Comment: NP. Glad you're cooking now.